# Align child div with child div from another parent possible in CSS?

Tags: css

I have the following genereated html:

```html
<div id="renderProduct1_control4">

  <!-- product description -->
  <div id="renderProduct1_identifierContainer">
    <div id="renderProduct1_identifier">Russell Hobbs Pennine 20444 Illuminating Kettle</div>
  </div>

  <div id="renderProduct1_control5">

    <!-- product sku -->
    <div id="renderProduct1_searchkey">RH2309574</div>

    <!-- product unit of measure -->
    <div id="renderProduct1_uom">Each</div>

    <!-- product price -->
    <div id="renderProduct1_priceBox">
      <div id="renderProduct1_control6">
        <div id="renderProduct1_price">£23.55</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- product brand name or series -->
    <div id="renderProduct1_series">Russell Hobbs</div>

    <!-- product manufacturer part number -->
    <div id="renderProduct1_brandcode">4008496875092</div>

    <!-- product in stock quantity -->
    <div id="renderProduct1_stock">14</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

I am trying to acheive the following:

[image]

But I can't find anywhere to give me an example of how to aligin the child "product identifier" with the child (from another parent) "searchkey".

My question is whether this is infact possible, as the html is already genereated for me, and I don't have an option to change that.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post css too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what an awful task... markup for tabular data should be an HTML table.. but anyway, you can sort of fake it with CSS grids and really specific content placement.

For taking care of the elements on different divs you can go with two different approaches: the most logical one would be to use display: contents so the unneeded containers don't affect the grid flow, but that would cause a major browser compatiblity issue. 
The other, probably best, would be to use two identical tables and overlay one over the other with absolute positioning:

```css
#renderProduct1_control4{
  position:relative;
}

#renderProduct1_identifierContainer{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  position:absolute;
  top:0; left:0;
  width:100%;
}

#renderProduct1_identifier{
  grid-row:1; grid-column: 2 / span 4;
}


#renderProduct1_control5{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
}


#renderProduct1_searchkey{
  grid-row:1; grid-column:1;
}

#renderProduct1_series{
  grid-row:2; grid-column:1;
}

#renderProduct1_brandcode{
  grid-row:2; grid-column:2;
}

#renderProduct1_uom{
  grid-row:2; grid-column:3;
}

#renderProduct1_stock{
  grid-row:2; grid-column:4;
}

#renderProduct1_priceBox{
  grid-row:2; grid-column:5;
}
```

```html
<div id="renderProduct1_control4">

  <!-- product description -->
  <div id="renderProduct1_identifierContainer">
    <div id="renderProduct1_identifier">Russell Hobbs Pennine 20444 Illuminating Kettle</div>
  </div>

  <div id="renderProduct1_control5">

    <!-- product sku -->
    <div id="renderProduct1_searchkey">RH2309574</div>

    <!-- product unit of measure -->
    <div id="renderProduct1_uom">Each</div>

    <!-- product price -->
    <div id="renderProduct1_priceBox">
      <div id="renderProduct1_control6">
        <div id="renderProduct1_price">£23.55</div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- product brand name or series -->
    <div id="renderProduct1_series">Russell Hobbs</div>

    <!-- product manufacturer part number -->
    <div id="renderProduct1_brandcode">4008496875092</div>

    <!-- product in stock quantity -->
    <div id="renderProduct1_stock">14</div>

  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Facundo! Your solution worked perfectly in my given situation.

Comment: @Shaarpe glad to help :)